# Fix fan-shaped scatter plot in R

Tags: r, regression

[image]

I get a similar scatter plot (as above) showing the relation between two different quantitative variables. It is also fan-shaped.

I am trying to fit a linear model for this relation. I think I should apply some kind of transformation to the variables in order to unify the ascent variance in the relation before fitting a linear regression model, but I can't find the way to do it. Or maybe, there is a better model to use in these cases, I can't either find it.

I have tried `rlm`, but when plotting the residuals vs the predictor they are very skewed. I have tried to use the weights retrieved by the model to transform the output:

```
fit <- rlm(y ~ x, data=df)
plot(fit$resid ~ df$x) # Heteroskedastic & Skewed

df$y <- df$y * fit$w 
plot(df$y ~ df$x) # Wrong
```

But it is obviously wrong.

I have also tried to apply a SD ratio calculated from all the y of each x and other similar erratic approaches.

Is there any typical way of fitting a model for this kind of relation (fan-shaped) or a typical model (and R package) to use in this cases?

Is there any typical transformation that could be applied to the variables in order to reduce the variance?

**Sorry, I duplicated the post: Follow [Fit regression model from a fan-shaped relation, in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156654/fit-regression-model-from-a-fan-shaped-relation-in-r), instead.**

Comment: How about natural logarithmic transformation for both Ca and Fe?

Comment: Log transform is a very good idea for this type of data, as @Penguin_Knight suggests. It also seems that there are different types of symbols on your plot, perhaps representing different individuals, different laboratories, or something like that. Is that true? If so, make sure you take those differences among observations into account in your model.

Comment: In addition, you can also see the dependence of spread on level using `car::spreadLevelPlot`.

Comment: Thank you all. I think I made a mistake and this post should be removed. I don't know how to move your answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156654/fit-regression-model-from-a-fan-shaped-relation-in-r, but I'll try it... Sorry for the mess!